# Displaying an error as "app " option required to reinstall while the appium program

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, appium

I am getting exception while running appium program. Please ask if extra information needed.

TLDR:

**original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall**

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall Build info:
>   version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time:
>   '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z' System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version:
>   AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app'
>   option is required for reinstall
>       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>       at asyncHandler (C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:83)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:72)
>     at Mobileapp1.Apptesting.main(Apptesting.java:24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you did not add "app" capability in your **DesiredCapability** and you are using **noReset** capability. You can add "app" capability and give .ipa or .apk file location.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "path to ipa/apk file" );
//others capabilities
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its IPA file or APK file?

Comment: for android it is apk and for ios it is ipa

Comment: Should I give mobile apk path or computer apk path?

Comment: you must give computer apk path

Comment: At some extend it helped me. However I am getting issue further, so I would raised new question instead of elongating it. Please have a look on those too. Thank you so much.